# como realizo una consulta sql de registros solo si existen en otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo dos tablas en la db

productos:
[image: tabla productos]

tienda:
[image: tabla tienda]

actualmente uso esta sentencia para seleccionar 10 items al azar de la tabla tienda

```
SELECT * FROM tienda WHERE id ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 10
```

mi duda es, como puedo hacer para que seleccione items de la tabla tienda si solo existen items en la tabla productos con el id de la tiendas?

es decir, guardo el id de la tienda en los productos(tienda), y al mostrar las tiendas quiero que me muestro solo las tiendas que tienen productos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que te refieres a algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM tienda WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT tienda FROM productos
  ) ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Y que, en el campo `tienda` de `productos`, estás guardando el `id` de la tienda.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para ampliar la respuesta lo mejor posible.

Comment: gracias, es justamente lo que buscaba

Comment: Genial, entonces vamos a dejarlo bien rematado: has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: hola david, una pregunta, en caso de que el producto tenga dos o mas id, como puedo realizar la misma consulta? actualmente me funciona bien solo si productos->tienda(id), pero en caso que haya productos->tienda(id,id,id,id), como puedo realizar dicha consulta?

Comment: Mejor formula una nueva pregunta y aporta las tablas implicadas con unos datos de muestra y lo que esperas obtener de éstos. Puedes utilizar phpMyAdmin, Exportar

Comment: es la misma pregunta, y las mismas tablas, nada cambia, solo que en vez de identificar un id comparándolo con un campo que tiene el mismo id, quiero identificar un id con un campo que tiene muchos id, es la misma sentencia, solo que dentro de IN () no debería ir una comparación, si no una búsqueda, se que con LIKE es posible pero no se como generar el id a buscar sin utilizar JOIN

Comment: algo asi quiero generar, SELECT * FROM tienda WHERE id IN ( SELECT tienda FROM productos WHERE tienda LIKE '%id%' ) ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 10; pero no comprendo como especificar el id

Comment: Para lo que esperas, debes usar la función `LOCATE()` en vez de ese `LIKE`. En las preguntas, es preferible evitar las captura de pantalla y utilizar código SQL, así es posible replicar rápidamente tu escenario y darle solución. Tú ves muy claro lo que quieres, pero para otra persona es más difícil de entender, sobre todo sin datos.

Comment: eres un genio! muchas gracias! logre realizar lo que quería con LOCATE()

Answer (score 1):

Has uso de inner join para vincular vas tablas por medio de la llave primaria en tienda que sería ID y de la llave foránea en productos que sería tienda

```
SELECT tienda.nombre
FROM tienda
INNER JOIN productos 
ON tienda.id = productos.tienda
ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, si funciona tal como quiero pero no utilizo el join ya que me remplaza ciertas filas(id, nombre, stock, usuario, enigma) y debo estar indicándole un nombre diferente para cada una en el join